# How can I create new faq categories in Vtiger?

Tags: categories, vtiger

That is.

I can't find the option for create a new faq category. Only "General" category appears.

How can I create a faq category in Vtiger 5.4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's simple, goes to the FAQ Module and Click on the "FAQ Settings" Icon and then Click on the left side menu in "Studio" link > "Picklist Editor" and then Select the Module "FQA", after you will show the "Category" in the "Select picklist" dropdown right side has "Add Item" button, click on this button and Add new entries here.